# How can I wrap a non-$http http request so that protractor waits for completion?

Tags: angularjs, protractor

I'm using a third party library (ipfs-js-api) to talk to a server. The problem is, this library does not use `$http` (since its not angular). How can I force protractor to wait for ipfs-js-api requests to finish before continuing.

I'd like to do this without `browser.wait()` in my tests.

For example, one (bad) solution would to create a fake `$timeout` (`$timeout(()=>{}, 100000000000000000`) which i cancel when the http request finishes. However this seems hacky and "wrong".

Comment: Why do you prefer not to use browser.wait? That's kind of what its for. Just write a function that returns true when your request finishes.

Comment: @CrhistianRamirez because I use the library about 100 times in my test and don't want to `browser.wait` every test

Comment: your question was "_How can I force protractor to wait_"?  that is the purpose of `browser.wait` - Schedules a command to wait for a condition to hold.